# Read a CSV with two Polygons(WKT) with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, csv, c++, well-known-text

I am trying to read a CSV file where the geometries of neighbouring polygons are stored in couples. The file looks like this.
[image]

I usually read  shapefiles in GDAL using the following syntax

```
GDALAllRegister();

GDALDataset       *poDS;
poDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx("shape.shp", GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL );
if( poDS == NULL )
{
    printf( "Open failed.\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}

OGRLayer  *poLayer;
poLayer = poDS->GetLayerByName("shape" ); // returns the layer that refers to the name (name.shp)
cout <<"There are " <<  poLayer -> GetFeatureCount() << "features"<<endl ;
OGRFeature *poFeature;
```

But this of course doesn't work. The documentation found here (http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/drv_csv.html) did not help me at all unfortunately.

I would like to know if there is a way to read this file in GDAL. I am coding in C++, but an answer in Python would be informative as well.

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Ideally I would like to scroll the file and populate a polygon class I have created for every single polygon. Which means two per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These look like Well Known Text fields.

You can load these with something like [Shapely, for example](https://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.geometry.html).

The example from the website linked is this:

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
g = loads('POINT (0.0 0.0)')
```

Obviously yours are polygons, but it should work the same.

In C++, you will be able to load it manually, if you need. Or there are likely a few libraries, such as [this one](https://github.com/Esri/ogc-crs-wkt-parser), that do it for you.

Edit: using [GDAL to parse WKT directly is documented here](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#create-geometry-from-wkt).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer;  unfortunately I can't use Shapely. I need to use GDAL, because my code is in C++, and GDAL exists for both python and C++, unlike shapely.

Comment: hi @DuccioPiovani, I've added another line pointing to the documentation on GDAL's geometry creation from WKT.

Comment: thank you very much. I can't up vote you because I need at least 15 points of reputation.

Comment: Can you mark the question as resolved, @DuccioPiovani? I get points from that ;-)